# find the dual pde-constrained optimization

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, dual-spaces, inverse-problems

Given a PDE-constrained optimization as
\begin{equation}
    \min_{u\in U} J(y,u)=\frac{1}{2}\|y-y_d\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}+\frac{\alpha}{2}\|u-u_d\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}
\end{equation}
subject to
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
        &-\Delta y=f+u, \text{in }\Omega,\\
        &y=0, \text{on }\partial\Omega,
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Let $y_\tau$ be the discretized solution, $p$ be the adjoint solution associated with $y$ and $p_\tau$ is the discretized solution as well. Define $e_y=y_\tau-y$ and $e_p=p-p_\tau$. The following 'dual' problem is introduced.
\begin{equation}
    \min_{q\in U} J(\phi,q)=\frac{1}{2}\|\phi-e_y\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}+\frac{\alpha}{2}\|q\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}
\end{equation}
subject to
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
        &-\alpha^{1/2}\Delta \phi=e_p+q, \text{in }\Omega,\\
        &\phi=0, \text{on }\partial\Omega,
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

---

It is not clear to me how this dual problem is formulated. Especially it mixed up the continuous and discrete space together. This is introduced in [the paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6420/ac4f5c) section 3.2.